# Is it valid to write $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{x^r}=2.\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ in limits?

Tags: limits

I'm wondering if it's valid to write the follwing: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{x^r}=2\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x^r}=2.\frac{1}{\infty}=2.0=0$$

I know it's valid to say that $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ in limits but I'm not suring if it would be valid to say $2.\frac{1}{\infty}=2.0=0$

Comment: As long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: Only if $r$ is positive.

Comment: @Nilknarf Yeah thanks, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the limit of a product is the product of the limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2}{x^r}= 2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^r}= 2\times 0=
0\, ,\qquad (r>0)\, 
$$
since $\lim_{x\to \infty}1/x^r=0$ for $r>0$.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid manipulating $\infty$ like numbers. your result is right just skip the step where you wrote $\frac 1 {\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

There are some operations with infinite limits that are valid. One of them is as follows:

Let $ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} $ and  $ (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} $ sequences of positive real numbres such that:

$ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} $ is bounded and  $\lim_{n \to \infty}
y_n = +\infty $

Then

$\lim_{n \to \infty}
{x_n}/{y_n} = 0 $.

This property remains valid if we consider functions rather than sequences. In this case, the constant function equal to 2 is bounded and the function $ x^r $ is such that it tends to infinity where $ x $ tends to infinity. Where $ r > 0 $.